# How do I add a keyboard shortcut to Froala for React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, froala

I'd like to wire `tab` to an action inside of Froala in a React project.

I've followed the example in the docs [the example in the docs](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/concepts/custom/shortcut), but pressing the target key doesn't seem to do anything.

I've set up a [code sandbox with a minimal reproduction of the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/froala-shortcut-broken-v4t69) (this code tries to assign the `1` key just to eliminate any complications with overloading the `tab` key). I've also included the code below.

The expected outcome is that pressing `1` inside of the editor will cause an alert to open. I know the alert action works, as I've also wired it to a button inside of Froala.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css";
import "froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css";
import "froala-editor/js/plugins/emoticons.min.js";
import "froala-editor/js/plugins/link.min.js";
import "froala-editor/js/third_party/spell_checker.min.js";
import "froala-editor/js/plugins/url.min.js";
import Editor from "react-froala-wysiwyg";
import Froala from "froala-editor";

import "./styles.css";

Froala.RegisterCommand("alert", {
  title: "Hello",
  focus: false,
  undo: false,
  refreshAfterCallback: false,
  callback: () => {
    alert("Hello!");
  }
});

Froala.RegisterShortcut(49, "alert");

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Editor
        config={{
          shortcutsEnabled: ["alert"],
          toolbarButtons: ["alert"]
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: `element.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyup)`? and your handler looks at the key code to determine if its a `1`... The event could be `keydown` | `keyup` | `keypress` But some dont fire for all keys others do. I think keyup is the correct one to use. `element` would be either the parent element that you want to capture on, or if its the whole page then you can put that on `document`

Comment: @JohnRuddell isn't this skipping the Froala APIs?

Comment: you can use the `initialized` callback in the config to [setup your listener](https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg/blob/master/demo/src/basic.jsx). Following the example they [posted for drag/drop](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/drop-content).. aka `editor.events.on('keyup',  ...)`